# How to free some space in /usr

Tags: shell-script, debian

How to free some space in /usr.I cant install new applications as /usr is taking 100% of space avialable

```
root@debian:/home/midhun# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           807M  9.4M  798M   2% /run
/dev/sda11       91G   11G   76G  12% /
/dev/sda13      9.2G  9.1G     0 100% /usr
tmpfs           4.0G   29M  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      9.2G   37M  8.6G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda16      9.2G  869M  7.8G  10% /usr/local
/dev/sda12       19G   18G   32M 100% /home
/dev/sda14      9.2G  4.6G  4.1G  53% /var
/dev/sda18      7.3G   34M  6.9G   1% /srv
/dev/sda19       15G   73M   14G   1% /boot
/dev/sda17      9.2G  1.2G  7.5G  14% /opt
tmpfs           807M   16K  807M   1% /run/user/115
tmpfs           807M   28K  807M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: /usr it's hard to free but uninstalling some useless softwares or games

Comment: is there some other way to extend space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you broke your disk space into partitions seems to be arbitrary and equally suboptimal and I'm not exactly sure why you did so in the first place but let's not talk about that.

I've noticed that your root partition

```
root@debian:/home/midhun# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda11       91G   11G   76G  12% /
```

has lots of free space and `/usr` has run out of space completely.

Here's how I'd approach this task - you'll **have** to boot from a live CD/USB flash to do the following:

1. Remove or comment out the `/usr` entry from `/etc/fstab`
2. `umount /usr/local` (just in case)
3. `cp -a --preserve=all /usr /usr-new`
4. `umount /usr`
5. `rmdir /usr`
6. `mv /usr-new /usr`

---

Alternatively you can run `sudo du -x /usr | sort -n | tail -30` and see which directories occupies the most space.

Then use `sudo dpkg-query -S /path` to find out which packages they belong to and remove them via `sudo apt remove packagename`.

Answer (score 0):

You did already by mounting a free disk/partition (/dev/sda16) to `/usr/local`. You can do the same to other "large" directories, but pls make sure you understand the ramifications as it adds to complexity and may leave the system in a hampered state.

Answer (score -1):

first run this to identify what are the largest dirs on your system

```
sudo du -k / | sort -n|tail -222
```

then  `rm` the give offending dirs in /home

you may want to just focus directly using

```
sudo du -k /home | sort -n|tail -222
sudo du -k /usr  | sort -n|tail -222
```

this will show large packages

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n
```

if you see some which you have installed recently and/or know you are not using they are candidates to remove

Another angle would be to view recently installed packages by issuing

```
grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

to see if any of those were optional and could be removed

Avoid directly removing anything in /usr as that contains critical system tools who's removal can cripple the system.  Instead identify optional packages then use the normal commands to remove those candidate packages.

```
sudo apt remove  unused-big-package    
sudo apt purge   unused-big-package # this also removes its configs
```

Comment: Um, no?  Just deleting stuff from `/usr` is _really bad advise_.  This will likely mean that the user will end up with an unusable system when system tools suddenly are missing.  A better answer along these lines (i.e. how to free space rather than how to enlarge the partition) would have shown how to find big installed packages and how to remove these properly (if they can be removed without crippling the system and/or user experience).